# GWT - how to change checkbox properties

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, uibinder

I have a (an?) `UiBinder` which creates checkbox element this way:

```
<g:CheckBox ui:field="ignoreCase"/>
```

in the java code, it uses this method to set the text

```
ignoreCase.setText(UIConverter.getUILocalization().get(UINames.IgnoreCase));
```

The result, in elements inspector is:

```
<span class="gwt-CheckBox FindEntDlgIgnoreCase">
    <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-255" tabindex="0">
    <label for="gwt-uid-255">Ignore case<label>
</span>
```

I want to add the `input` element style property: `margin-left:5px`, but I don't find a way to get the `input` element.

How can I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do:

```
ignoreCase.getElement().getChild(0)
```

Another option is to create a CSS rule that you can apply consistently every time you need this margin. For example:

```
.myBox input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

You can set this class programmatically on your checkbox, or add it in UiBinder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:style>
    .mystyle {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
</ui:style>
```

Use "styleName" property to add static styles to your GWT elements:

```
<g:CheckBox ui:field="ignoreCase" styleName="{style.mystyle}" />
```

or using your ui:field access element from Java class:

```
@UiField ignoreCase;

...

ignoreCase.addStyleName("mystyle");
```

Comment: The OP is not trying to add a margin to a GWT checkbox, but to an `input` element.